# How to align multi-line text in an <ul> not with the bullet point, but with the text above?

Tags: html, css, text

Is it possible to align multi-line text of an `<li>` of an `<ul>` with the text itself, not with the  bullet point? The standard way it's rendered is that there is an indentation for the first line of text next to the bullet point, but not for the other lines below it. So the second, third, etc. lines all align with the bullet point, not with the first line of text. E.g.:

[image: Text aligned with bullet points]

As you can see in the above image, the text is aligned with the bullet points. So for example in the first `<li>`, I need "throughout" to be directly under "Get", not under the bullet point.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The normal HTML renders in the way to need, can you share a sample code snippet

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - This allows us to provide more accurate answers and increases the chances of your problem being solved.

Comment: Make sure <ul> tag isn't missing around <li> elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, html does show the lists as you want. The example you use has been manipulated to show it that way.

Without the code of your example we can't know how to "fix" that problem or why the list is behaving that way.

```css
ul {width:200px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>indentation for the first line of text next to the bullet point, but not for the other lines below it.</li>
  <li>indentation for the first line of text next to the bullet point, but not for the other lines below it.</li>
  <li>indentation for the first line of text next to the bullet point, but not for the other lines below it.</li>
  <li>indentation for the first line of text next to the bullet point, but not for the other lines below it.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see. Thank you...it's in WordPress, using Avada theme. I will check their CSS to see what is causing this deviation from the standard behavior.